# How to use System.Configuration.Install.Installer located in separate DLL when installing exe as service?

Tags: c#, dll, windows-services

I have created a DLL which contains a helper class and `Installer` for installing an exe as a Windows service using command line arguments. I call this helper method from within the main method of another console application project which only contains a class which implements `ServiceBase`.

The usage is as follows:

```
//In console application project
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    return new ServiceInstallHelper<MyServiceType>("ServiceName").Run(args);
}
```

Internally `ServiceInstallHelper` calls

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location });
```

to install the exe as a service.

The problem is that since the Installer class lives inside the DLL and not the exe assembly when I try to run this code from my console application it says there is no Installer in the assembly.

I can fix this by adding a class in the console application project which inherits from the Installer in the DLL:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class Installer : ProjectInstaller
{
}
```

but I am looking for a way to make this work without this extra class.

The problem comes down to the fact that the argument to `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` is supposed to be an exe assembly to install as a service, but it seems to also expect a `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` to exist in that same assembly, whereas my `Installer` exists in a different assembly.

Comment: Can't you just use `typeof(SomethingInTheLibrary).Assembly.Location` ? Perhaps `typeof(ProjectInstaller).Assembly.Location` ? (instead of `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`, which is the exe)

Comment: @MarcGravell But then it thinks I am trying to install my DLL as a service, which doesn't work.

Comment: @mclaassen, did you manage to overcome this problem ?

Comment: I've recently run into this same problem (moving my `Installer` class to a common dll to keep code consistent, see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49298429)). Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Ofiris Seeing as you seem to have had this problem too did you ever find a solution to it? (See my above comment).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Service Installer class run in a different Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298429/can-the-service-installer-class-run-in-a-different-assembly)