# Can the Service Installer class run in a different Assembly?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a custom Installer class that is used when installing my Windows Service. Stripped down to the necessary details the class looks like this.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyWindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public MyWindowsServiceInstaller()
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = Program.ServiceDetails.Name;
        serviceInstaller.Description = Program.ServiceDetails.Description;

        //Must be the same as what was set in Program's constructor
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = Program.ServiceDetails.Name;

        Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

The service is then installed through code by calling the following class, depending on arguments passed into the service, like so. This is called from inside of `Main`.

```
using (ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(program.ModuleName, typeof(Program).Assembly))
{
    serviceHandler.InstallService();
}
```

Where the `ServiceHandler` class is (again stripped down to remove noise).

```
public class ServiceHandler : IDisposable
{
    private ServiceController _serviceController;
    private AssemblyInstaller _assemblyInstaller;

    public ServiceHandler(string serviceName, Assembly assembly)
    {
        _serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName);

        _assemblyInstaller = new AssemblyInstaller(assembly, null);
        _assemblyInstaller.UseNewContext = true;
    }

    public void InstallService()
    {
        if (IsServiceInstalled())
        {
            return;
        }

        IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
        try
        {
            _assemblyInstaller.Install(state);
            _assemblyInstaller.Commit(state);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                _assemblyInstaller.Rollback(state);
            }
            catch { }
            throw;
        }
    }

    public bool IsServiceInstalled()
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceControllerStatus status = _serviceController.Status;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

However, at the moment all of our services use the same `MyWindowsServiceInstaller` but copied into each project separately. To resolve this I was going to move that class to a common assembly with some other functionality (and remove the coupling of the class with `Program`) but I'm not sure if it's possible to have the `Installer` in another assembly.

Is this possible? If so how do I go about it?

---

I imagine another problem with my approach is the `typeof(Program).Assembly` call to create the `ServiceHandler` but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, that ought to work okay.  It is *because* you use typeof(Program).Assembly that it can still get to a good end.  If not then add "assemblypath" to the HashTable.  Using non-standard install procedures, oof, bad idea.  This is going to blow up when you're not around, when the admin tries to configure the service with a non-privileged account.  Install fail, can't write to the registry.  Talking SO users out of lethal code is such an unpleasant task.

Comment: @HansPassant FWIW this is the first step to install the services, a second step then runs to change the account. The thing that I was confused about though is that I'm passing the Assembly for Program in and the Installer is then no longer in that Assembly so that doesn't look like it would work to me. On the note of lethal code we've actually had less problems with the current approach than the standard way with `InstallUtil` and what not.

Comment: @HansPassant A quick try on this shows it doesn't work (or at least I've done it incorrectly). Having the `MyWindowsServiceInstaller` in a different assembly to the main one doesn't work because there's no installer in `typeof(Program).Assembly`. Passing in `typeof(ServiceHandler).Assembly` also doesn't work because then the installed service points to the dll not the exe.

Comment: Installer looks into the assembly and looking for `[RunInstaller(true)]` attribute. That's why you can not put it into another assembly. Try to put an inherited empty class into the assembly.
`[RunInstaller(true)] public class PutThisIntoYourAssmebly: MyWindowsServiceInstaller {}` and remove attribute from your original installer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installer looks into the assembly and looking for [RunInstaller(true)] attribute. Only think you should do: Mark for installer witch is your installer class. Put an inherited empty class into your main assembly.

Common Assembly:

```
//[RunInstaller(true)] <<-- REMOVE this
public class MyWindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
{
   public MyWindowsServiceInstaller(){
    ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller = new 
    ServiceProcessInstaller();
    ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

    processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

    serviceInstaller.DisplayName = Program.ServiceDetails.Name;
    serviceInstaller.Description = Program.ServiceDetails.Description;

    //Must be the same as what was set in Program's constructor
    serviceInstaller.ServiceName = Program.ServiceDetails.Name;

    Installers.Add(processInstaller);
    Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

Main assembly

```
[RunInstaller(true)] // <<-- put it here
public class ProjectInstaller : MyWindowsServiceInstaller { }
```

Comment: This works well, wasn't exactly what I had in mind but it does the job quite well.

Comment: Just a minor note that you can actually leave the `RunInstaller` attribute on the base `MyWindowsServiceInstaller` class.  You don't have to move it to the derived class in the installation assembly provided the class inherits from `MyWindowsServiceInstaller`.